# Changing an existing master-data role node to a data node only

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, cluster-computing

I have an `elastic cluster` with multiple nodes. I intend to dynamically change an existing node that currently serves both the "`master`" and "`data`" roles to exclusively perform the "`data`" role, all without causing any downtime. What would be the optimal approach to achieve this?

Changing the configuration and restarting the cluster with new settings

Comment: How many other master nodes do you have in your cluster? Can you briefly explain the topology?